# Unexpected token if (syntaxerror)

Tags: javascript

i don't know where the error is
it gives me unexpected token if
and i've done everything to solve it and still no hope:

```
    var sleepCheck = function (numHours)

    if(numHours >= 8) {
        return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!"
    } 
    else {
        return "Get some more shut eye!";
    }

    sleepCheck(10)
    sleepcheck(5)
    sleepcheck(8)
```

Comment: You're missing curly braces {} around the function body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 errors: 
- function without {} 
- sleepCheck written as sleepcheck (2 last calls)

```
var sleepCheck = function (numHours){
if(numHours >= 8) {
    return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!"
} 
else {
    return "Get some more shut eye!";
}
}

sleepCheck(10);
sleepCheck(5);
sleepCheck(8);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hda3bxnr/1/

Comment: This looks right, but what's the point of a fiddle with no visible or console output?

Comment: it was just an exercise and an intro for using functions and if/else situation

Comment: @nnnnnn you made a point, it was just to check for the syntax.
I've update with console output

Answer (score 3):

Your function doesn't have the curly brackets:

```js
var sleepCheck = function (numHours){

    if(numHours >= 8) {
        return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!"
    } 
    else {
        return "Get some more shut eye!";
    }
};

    console.log(sleepCheck(10));
    console.log(sleepCheck(5));
    console.log(sleepCheck(8));
```

Besides that, check the upper case: `sleepCheck`, not `sleepcheck`.

Comment: that just did it!!